# How to remove decimals from label using scale_fill_distiller in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently using the following line of code in one of my plots using ggplot2 to add a scale to my charts:

`scale_fill_distiller(labels = comma, trans = "log10", palette = "Greens", direction = 1) +`

But this results in a scale that has a single decimal at the end. How would I go about rounding these to whole numbers? I want to keep the commas in there.

Comment: What about instead of `comma` you use `comma_format(accuracy = 1)`?

Comment: If you submit that as a solution, I can accept it!